# How to create console Tail functionality with MaterialUI TextField component as Console for web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield, multiline

***Current Behavior of Component: not scrolling up as new content is added to textField:***
[image: example]

I am currently trying to create a live console in a react application and was hoping to just leverage materialUI's TextField as I'm already using MaterialUI in my app. I am currently able to stream data from our websocket and log it to the console, but the console does not scroll with the new data on state change.

My question is, is there a way to achieve this behavior? My initial thought was to hook into the onChange event built into the TextField component but I wasn't sure how to set the focus to the last line of the TextField. Maybe there is a way to do this with CSS? Sample Code is posted below.

I am not able to share the actual code so hopefully I don't miss too much in this pseudocode. Go easy on me as I'm pretty green ;)

```
const Console = () => {
const [data, setData] = useState('');

const consoleOut = (message) => {
  setData((state) => {
    state = state + message + '\n'
    return state
  })
}

//Assume Ref to Websocket
ws.current.on("message", (data) => {
  // streams message into consoleState
  const {message} = data
  consoleOut(message)
}


return (
  <TextField
    autoFocus
    multiline
    rows={10}
    fullWidth
    value={data}
    id="console-output"
    label="Console"
    disabled
  />
)

}

return default Console
```

I have explored the API provided by MaterialUI and do not see any supplied props that would allow this kind of behavior.

I have also explored the possibility of using the onChange hook supplied by MaterialUI and directly manipulating the textField following state change during the consoleOut function. I think this may be the most direct way of achieving this behavior, but it would require that I know how to change the focus to the last line of the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is define a [`ref`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) for your input, pass it as an [`inputRef`](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/text-field/#props) to the [`Textfield`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/) component, and then update the `scrollTop` position for the underlying input when your data changes.  For example:

```
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      // Where the magic happens
      inputRef.current.scrollTop = inputRef.current.scrollHeight;
    }
  }, [data]);
```

```
  <TextField
    inputRef={inputRef}
    autoFocus
    multiline
    rows={10}
    fullWidth
    value={data}
    id="console-output"
    label="Console"
    disabled
  />
```

***Working CodeSandbox:*** https://codesandbox.io/s/fragrant-resonance-48m7d6?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: FYI you do not need to do `textfieldRef && textfieldRef.current`. Ref objects are never null. It is enough to do `if (textfieldRef.current)`. And you do not even need to have that if statement if you know that the text field will always exist in the ui

Comment: @zoran404 Fair enough -- updated.  Thanks!